# STAF: How do I redirect the output of the process started by STAF to hudson console instantaneously?

Tags: hudson

I am starting a ruby command from a batch file using STAF.

**STAF $TESTMACHINE process start command ruby "C:\MyProject\scripts\MasterScript.rb" WAIT SAMECONSOLE RETURNSTDERR RETURNSTDOUT WORKDIR "C:\MyProject\scripts"**

This batch file is triggered by a Hudson job. But my observation is that the print/puts of the ruby files appear in the hudson console only after the completion of the execution of the ruby script [Hudson job]. This way I can not make out if something is going wrong in the script execution unless the job completes.

Also, I understand that if I remove RETURNSTDERR RETURNSTDOUT, the ruby script's output is displayed in the STAF console on the target machine. So STAF is the one which is sending back the ruby outputs to the hudson console.

Now can I use any option with STAF to get the ruby output spontaneously to the hudson console?

Thanks for reading this lengthy question :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use SSH instead of STAF for such task.

It seems with STAF it's a little bit tricky and could be done with OUTPUT option.
If you have shared storage, for example NFS share called /nfs on hudson server and d:\nfs on Windows, the following hudson job should work:

**STAF $TESTMACHINE process start command ruby "C:\MyProject\scripts\MasterScript.rb" WAIT SAMECONSOLE RETURNSTDERR RETURNSTDOUT WORKDIR "C:\MyProject\scripts" OUTPUT "d:\nfs\hudson.log" &


tail --pid=$! -f /nfs/hudson.log**

Comment: It looks like you bolded instead of marking as code. `\`` and four spaces can be used to mark as code.